# Convert Database Date to string from java script

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to convert **row.visitDate** to string. Now it will display like -  /Date(1581376680000)/

View

```
<code>
    <div> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AmcvId, new SelectList(""), "--Select Visit--", new { @id = "AmcvId", @class = "form-control" })</div>

</code>
<script>
     $.get("/ComplaintRegistration/GetAmcVisitList", { AmcId: $("#AmcId").val() }, function (data) {
                        $("#AmcvId").empty();
                        $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                            $("#AmcvId").append("<option value='" + row.AmcVisitId + "'>" + row.VisitDate + "</option>")
                        });
                    });
 </script>
```

Controller:

```cs
public ActionResult GetAmcVisitList(int AmcId)
{
    List<AMCVisitDetails> AmcVisitList = new List<AMCVisitDetails>();
    AmcVisitList = db.AmcVisitDetails.Where(t => t.AmcId== AmcId).ToList();

    return Json(AmcVisitList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm parsing .net dates like this.

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(row.visitDate.substr(6)));

date.toLocaleDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The value displayed which looks like some random garbage number is actually a `timestamp` value represented in `miliseconds`.
Inorder to convert Timestamp to proper human readable date, simply pass this Timestamp  to the `Date` constructor.

```
var visitDate = new Date(row.AmcVisitId); //new Date(1581376680000) gives "Mon Feb 10 2020 18:18:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
```

Now you can format it as you prefer for displaying it in the Page.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
new Date(row.VisitDate).toLocaleString()
```

Comment: This will not work, result same as it is .                                                               $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                        $("#AmcvId").append("<option value='" + row.AmcVisitId + "'>" + new Date(row.VisitDate).toLocaleString() + "</option>")   
                    });